# Adding a reference from a winform to an excel workbook

Tags: vb.net, winforms, excel

I have a combined project on VS2012, the main project is a winform the second project is an Excel workbook. I need to access some of the forms on the workbook from my winform. I added a reference to the workbook by:

Add Reference>bin>Debug>Compensation Workbook.dll (name of the file)

However, when I start or debug the project it is telling me that something else is using that file. I have checked and nothing is using that file.

Am I adding the reference correctly, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Try 'cleaning' the solution and rebuilding.  Sometime VS has problems letting go of a reference on a previous build.

Comment: Rarely is it that easy :-)  Time to take a break...